# What is the best practice for managing relationships using POST and PATCH in a RESTful API when the opposite entity already exists?

Tags: rest, api, relationship, entity-relationship

I am designing a RESTful API and my questions is the following: What is the best practice for managing relationships using POST and PATCH in a RESTful API? Where and when should I allow the consumer of the API to establish relationships between entities when the opposite entity/entities already exists/exist? My goals are to (a) minimize code and code maintenance with (b) a balanced ratio of easiness to understand the API and number of API calls to establish relationships. The most limiting criterion is that I am developing and maintaining the API on my own.

If it is of any interest, I am using ASP.NET Core and separated the API (with outer facing models) and the entity framework based data layer (with data models) into two different layers, where the API layer references the data layer (API -> Data).

I would like to discuss all possible combinations of the http request methods POST and PATCH and the three types of relationships one-to-one, one-to-many and many-to-many.

**POST one-to-one**

I was thinking about allowing the consumer of the API to let the POST request for the new entity only go through when the opposite entity has *no* relationship to any other entity of the posted entity type.

Another option would be to never allow setting relationships through POST but only let it update via PATCH. I favor this option, because it makes the entity easier and saver to create when treating the relationships separately. Even better, it would only require two API calls - one for POSTing the new entity and one for PATCHing even multiple relationships to many different one-to-one opposite entities.

**POST one-to-many**

One option would be allowing the consumer of the API to let the POST for the new entity only go through when *all* of the opposite entities have no relationship to any other entity of the posted entity type. Less save would be to allow the consumer to override existing relationships of the opposite entity to another entity of the type of the posted entity.

Another option would be to not allow posting any relationship of a single entity to many entities, because the relationships are effectively set in the opposite entities anyway. I prefer to only allow setting the relationship in the opposite entities via PATCH since this is the place where the many to one relationship is effectively established, and it keeps the creation of the entity separated from establishing relationships.

**POST many-to-many**

I would never allow to set a relationship for a POST request in a many-to-many relationship, but only allow to PATCH new relationships on both the new entity and the opposite entity. Due to the complexity of this type of relationship, I think it is best keep the entity creation as easy as possible and manage relationships separately through PATCH requests.

---

**PATCH one-to-one**

I would set no restrictions and allow the consumer of the API to set the relationship freely on both sides.

**PATCH one-to-many**

This one is a real dilemma for me - number of API calls vs easiness to understand relationships and lines of code.

On the one hand, I could allow to PATCH from the single entity point of view (it contains for example an array of opposite entity IDs). This would require only one API call to update the relationships of the multiple opposite entities, but this requires more code, because the data layer needs find and loop through all opposite entities. In addition, updating from the single entity point of view is sometimes hard to understand for me - many times its easier for me to establish the relationships in all opposite entities that refer to the same single entity.

On the other hand, I could allow the consumer of the API to update all opposite entities individually. This would require many API calls, but I sometimes think updating from this point of view is easier to understand, and the relationship is effectively set in the multiple opposite entities anyway.

I don't know what to favor yet. I am thinking about offering both options.

**PATCH many-to-many**

The only way I can see is to allow the consumer of the API to allow setting relationships on both sides due to the nature of this relationship.

---

While elaborating my ideas above, I think the best guideline is to keep creation of entities completely separated from establishing relationships and to set the relationships only where they are effectively established (mimicking SQL table behavior). I assume the latter one is what most API consumers should be familiar with and the first one keeps the API save and simple (at the cost of efficiency).

Please let me know if I missed any cases, criteria for decision making or didn't think of any implementation strategies.

Best regards,
philippfx